# Pandas: Add new samples where output difference is high

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with two columns, `x` and `y`. Initially `x` is uniformly distributed in a range. `y` is calculated as `y = some_function(x)`.

Now I want to see the difference in subsequent values of `y` and if it is beyond a certain value, I want to add more sample points between the corresponding two x values. `x_new = (x1 + x2)/2.0`

I wrote a small function for this purpose, but is there an easy way I am missing?

```
def dense1(data):
    data = data.sort_values(by='x')
    dy = data['y'].diff()
    dx = data['x'].diff()
    i = np.abs(dy) > 0.1
    new_x = data['x'][i] - dx[i]/2.0
    return new_x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon a closer inspection, it seems we can avoid one `diff` there and that simplifies it a bit.

That leads to a NumPy version, like so -

```
a = data.values
mask = np.abs(np.diff(a[:,1])) > 0.1
out_arr = ((a[1:,0] + a[:-1,0])/2.0)[mask]
```

That translates to a pandas version, like so -

```
mask = data['y'].diff().abs() > 0.1
out = ((data.x.shift(1) + data.x)/2.0)[mask]
```

Sample run -

```
In [471]: np.random.seed(0)

In [472]: data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2), columns=(('x','y')))

In [473]: data = data.sort_values(by='x')
     ...: dy = data['y'].diff()
     ...: dx = data['x'].diff()
     ...: i = np.abs(dy) > 0.1
     ...: new_x = data['x'][i] - dx[i]/2.0
     ...: 

In [474]: new_x
Out[474]: 
3    0.430621
0    0.493200
1    0.575788
4    0.783213
Name: x, dtype: float64

In [476]: mask = data['y'].diff().abs() > 0.1
     ...: out = ((data.x.shift(1) + data.x)/2.0)[mask]
     ...: 

In [477]: out
Out[477]: 
3    0.430621
0    0.493200
1    0.575788
4    0.783213
Name: x, dtype: float64
```